# Is $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$ true?

Tags: probability

I am trying to find the proof for this property but I can't seem to get anywhere. Can anyone help me?

$E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$

Comment: Maybe because it's absolutely not true in general? See, if it was, then Var$X=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$ would always be $0$...

Comment: This is the definition of $X$ and $Y$ being *uncorrelated*. To have independence, we need a larger set of test functions, such as requiring $E[f(X)g(Y)] = E[f(X)]E[g(Y)]$ for every bounded measurable functions $f, g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @SangchulLee I was thinking probability, not expectation.  My mind is going.

Comment: @saulspatz, That's what I suspected. No worries, I also make tons of silly mistakes even when I am sober. :s

Comment: You can safely assume as a rule of thumb that outside of rather sectorial courses you won't find mathematical objects that take values in $\Bbb R$ and are both linear and multiplicative (unless explicitly said).

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample:

$X$ is bernoulli with probability $\frac12$, and $Y=1-X$

Hence $XY=0$, $\mathbb{E}[XY]=0$ but $\mathbb{E}(X)=\mathbb{E}(Y)=\frac12$.

Comment: +1 You mean $E[XY]=0$ Siong ?

Comment: ah yup, coincidencely, $XY=0$ as well. ;P thanks.

Comment: No, it was on purpose. $XY=0$ certainly, since $X$ is either $0$ or $1$; so $X(1-X)=0$.  Which does make $\mathsf E(XY)=0$

Comment: Ah ok @GrahamKemp Thanks for correcting me